# use of variable inside render function of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and came across a doubt, there are two codes in which variables used by render method in component are declared at different places, my doubt is why one works and other doesn't.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'reactDOM';

const myVar = 'hello';

class myComponent extends React.Component {
    render () {
       return <h1>{myVar}</h1>;
    }
}

ReactDOM(
    <myComponent />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

This works, means I am able to access global variable in render method.

But take this case which does not work

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'reactDOM';

class myComponent extends React.Component {
    const myVar = 'hello';

    render () {
       return <h1>{this.myVar}</h1>;
    }
}

ReactDOM(
    <myComponent />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I am confused here, can somebody explain this behavior

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside the class you don't define variables. You just have to write `myVar='hello'` not `const myVar='hello'`

> Properties specified in a class definition are assigned the same attributes as if they appeared in an object literal.